# Raspberry Pi GPIO Interrupt callback variable

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, interrupt, gpio

So I have a pretty simple question which I haven't found the answer to anywhere around here. Simply put, I define a callback function which requires a variable, and that variable may change. Do I need to remove event detection on that pin, then add it again to get the callback associated with the event to use the new variable value on next event?

```
def t_doSomething(var):
    print(var)
var = 'foo'
channel = 17
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=t_doSomething(var) bouncetime=200)
#Event called by rising edge prints 'foo'
#Change the variable.
var = 'bar'
#Event called a second time prints...?
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say I assume the value of the variable may change. Also assuming the environment is raspbian Linux not (windows 10 IoT core etc) what you do should work. After you change the variable, when you call the function again or when you put it in a loop of some sort. The new printed value should be the new value of the "var". So #1 below should print "foo" and #2 should print "bar".

```
def t_doSomething(var):
print(var)
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=t_doSomething(var)bouncetime=200)

var = 'foo'
channel = 17
    #Change the variable.
var = 'bar'
 do_something()
if GPIO.event_detected(channel):
print(var)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would I need to add event detection again once the variable has changed, or are you using the numbers to indicate the times at which an event is detected?

Comment: Sorry just edited it to clear the misunderstanding. You only have to add event detection once. Then add an if as shown above to fire up when it changes.

Comment: The idea is that t_doSomething is called via the event detection as it's callback, not that it is called by itself.

Comment: Great question btw! the event detection should be global scope. so I don't think it would effect anything. As a matter of fact you might want to add it outside of the function. From there on it should act as a normal function, since the event detection is treated like a different thread. It will fire up regardless of the current state of the program. At the end of the day it will print the value of var whenever a "rising edge" is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not pass the function, but call it and pass its result. Instead

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=t_doSomething,bouncetime=200)
```

would have passed the function instead. It is not possible to pass a variable to this callback. You would need to work with global variables instead.